# Custom handler in Strapi

Tags: customization, strapi, user-permissions

I'm trying to create a custom route and handler for user-permissions but it's not working. Not sure though if my method is wrong or cannot be done. By the way here is my code.

**/config/routes.json**

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "PUT",
      "path": "/users/:id/approve",
      "handler": "users.approve",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**/controllers/Users.js**

```
module.exports = {
    approve: async ctx => {
        const { id } = ctx.params;
        console.log('approve user')
    }
};
```

From routes, the handler should read the `approve` in controller but the strapi threw error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'approve' of undefined`

Comment: `strapi-plugin-user-permissions`'s original controller file is called [`User.js`](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/controllers/User.js) without an "s". Also, I'm pretty sure the first part of the `handler` property should match exactly the file name, it should be `User` (capitalized).

Comment: Glad I could help :)